# Can you use ADO to extract a hyperlink's URL address (ie, without opening the workbook)?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, ado

I have >500 workbooks, each with a single sheet containing 50 to 2000 rows of data.  I need to consolidate them into a single spreadsheet.  One of my columns consists of hyperlinks which on the worksheet is displayed simply as the 'friendly name' LINK.  The quickest way I've found to consolidate these sheets is using ADO, but when I do this the resulting sheet contains no hyperlinks, just the text LINK.

I'm using Dir to loop through all my files. With each file, I use code like this (where fn is the filename):

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim oc As New ADOX.Catalog, tt As New ADOX.Table
Dim sql As String, ss As String,  lr As Double 

With cn
      .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & fn & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"""
      .Open
End With
Set oc.ActiveConnection = cn

For Each tt In oc.Tables
            ss = tt.Name
            sql = "SELECT * FROM [" & ss & "]"  'ss ends in $
            rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
            rs.Open sql, cn
            rs.MoveFirst
            'paste data into worksheet:
            lr = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            Sheet2.Range("A" & lr + 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
            rs.Close
            Set rs = Nothing
Next tt
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

So my question, can I extract the link's URL address using this ADO approach?
I know I can do that if I open each file individually (Workbooks.Open fn) and on the relevant worksheet (ws) loop through each row (r) in the relevant column (R), like this:
ws.Range("R" & r).Hyperlinks(1).Address

But with my antiquated computer at least it's the file opening that takes so long.  So I'm hoping there's a way to do this with ADO.
Thanks for any help you can offer.